# Add a custom directory localtexmf to Texlive on MacOS (Monterey)

Tags: texlive, macos

I have a directory (coming from MikTeX) named localtexmf which contains all sorts of personal files (fonts I purchased, some .cls files etc.) which I need. I knew how to add the directory to MikTeX under Win10. Now I have an Imac with MacOS (which is completely new for me) and I do not know how to tell texlive that it should read that additional directory when compiling. Please consider I am a newbie of macos. Any help? Thanks.

Maurizio

Thanks to all.

First attempt:

```
tlmgr conf texmf TEXMFHOME /Users/maurizio/localtexmf/

tlmgr: setting texmf TEXMFHOME to /Users/maurizio/localtexmf/ (in /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf.cnf)

Cannot write to /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf.cnf: Permission denied
```

---

However I am still uncomfortable with Terminal etc. (as I told you I have no experience with MacOS). I find very strange that for such a simple problem one has to go through this. On Win with MikTeX it was trivial.

Maurizio

Comment: Can you try `tlmgr conf texmf TEXMFHOME  /path/to/your/localtexmf/folder/`?

Comment: Or you could check what you already have as location with `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME` and place your files there (is probably something like `~/Librray/texmf/` by default)

Comment: Assuming you installed TeX Live using the MacTeX installer you can place the personal files in proper sub-directories of  `~/Library/texmf`. Note: `~/Library/` is the Library foldeer in your HOME folder, NOT `/Library` at the root of your HD/SSD. You can get more information about installing fonts by downloading `TeXLive2019Changes.pdf.zip` from [https://herbs.github.io](https://herbs.github.io).